# Isomorphism between $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ and an irreducible conic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to show that the map $\phi:\mathbb{P}^{1}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{2}, (a:b)\mapsto (a^{2}:b^{2}:ab)$ is an isomorphism onto its image.

Im able to show that $\text{im}(\phi) = Z(z^{2}-xy)\subset\mathbb{P}^{2}$. To prove that $\phi$ is a morphism, it is enough to show this locally. Notice that $\mathbb{P}^{1} = D(a)\cup D(b)$, where $D(a) = \{(a:b)\rvert a\neq 0\}$. Then consider $\phi_{\rvert_{D(a)}}: D(a)\rightarrow U_{0}, (1:b)\mapsto (1:b^{2}:b)$ where $U_{0}=\{(x:y:z)\rvert  x\neq 0\}$. Notice that this map is a morphism if and only if the map $g:\mathbb{A}^{1}\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{2}, b\mapsto (b^{2},b)$ is a morphism. But this is clearly true since $b,b^{2}\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{1}}(\mathbb{A}^{1})$. We can use the same reasoning to prove that $\phi_{\rvert{D(b)}}$ is a morphism. Consequently since $\phi$ is locally a morphism we find that $\phi$ is a morphism.

Let $C = Z(z^{2}-xy)$. For the inverse map we find that it is given by

$\psi: C\backslash\{(1:0:0)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}, (x:y:z)\mapsto (z:y)$

$: C\backslash\{(0:1:0)\}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}, (x:y:z)\mapsto (x:z)$.

And we indeed see that it is well-defined (they agree on $C\backslash\{(1:0:0),(0:1:0)\}$. Now to prove that it is a morphism I want to use the same strategy by looking at it locally. But my problem is on which local opens I have to check this. I would like to reduce it to checking whether a map on an open $U\subset\mathbb{A}^{n}$ for some $n$ to some closed $Y\subset \mathbb{A}^{m}$ for some $m$ is a morphism (just like the $g$ in the process of proving that $\phi$ is a morphism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your inverse should be

$\psi : C \setminus \{ (1:0:0) \} \to \mathbb{P}^1, (x : y : z) \mapsto (z : y)$

$ : C \setminus \{ (0:1:0) \} \to \mathbb{P}^1, (x : y : z) \mapsto (x : z)$.

Then to check that it is a morphism you can use the restricted standard affine cover $U_i \cap C$, $i=0,1,2$ on $C$, which are isomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^2$. On the image you can use the standard affine cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

For example on $U_0 \cap C$ we get $(y,z) \mapsto z$ in affine coordinates as a map from a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^2$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$ and you can see that it is regular.

Comment: You are right about the inverse. Let $Y$ be the closed subset of your example. I forgot about the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y) = k[y,z]/(z^{2}-y)$ in this particular example you gave. Consequently we indeed easily see that this map is regular. The other cases are indeed the same.